# optimize pandas query on multiple columns / multiindex

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bigdata

I have a very large table (currently 55 million rows, could be more), and I need to select subsets of it and perform very simple operations on those subsets, lots and lots of times.  It seemed like pandas might be the best way to do this in python, but I'm running into optimization problems.

I've tried to create a fake dataset that closely matches my real dataset (although it's ~5-10 times smaller).  This is still big, takes a lot of memory, etc.  There are four columns that I'm querying on, and two that I'm using for calculations.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import timeit

n=10000000
mdt = pandas.DataFrame()
mdt['A'] = np.random.choice(range(10000,45000,1000), n)
mdt['B'] = np.random.choice(range(10,400), n)
mdt['C'] = np.random.choice(range(1,150), n)
mdt['D'] = np.random.choice(range(10000,45000), n)
mdt['x'] = np.random.choice(range(400), n)
mdt['y'] = np.random.choice(range(25), n)


test_A = 25000
test_B = 25
test_C = 40
test_D = 35000

eps_A = 5000
eps_B = 5
eps_C = 5
eps_D = 5000


f1 = lambda : mdt.query('@test_A-@eps_A <= A <= @test_A+@eps_A  &  ' +
                        '@test_B-@eps_B <= B <= @test_B+@eps_B  &  ' +
                        '@test_C-@eps_C <= C <= @test_C+@eps_C  &  ' +
                        '@test_D-@eps_D <= D <= @test_D+@eps_D')
```

This selects (for my random dataset) 1848 rows:

```
len(f1())
Out[289]: 1848
```

And it takes about .1-.15 seconds per query:

```
timeit.timeit(f1,number=10)/10
Out[290]: 0.10734589099884033
```

So I thought I must be able to do better by sorting and indexing the table, right?  And I can take advantage of the fact that everything is an int, so I can do slices..

```
mdt2 = mdt.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sortlevel()

f2 = lambda : mdt2.loc[(slice(test_A-eps_A, test_A+eps_A),
                        slice(test_B-eps_B, test_B+eps_B),
                        slice(test_C-eps_C, test_C+eps_C),
                        slice(test_D-eps_D, test_D+eps_D)), :]

len(f2())
Out[299]: 1848
```

And it takes a *lot* longer:

```
timeit.timeit(f2,number=10)/10
Out[295]: 7.335134506225586
```

Am I missing something here?  It seems like I could do something like numpy.searchsorted, but I can't think of how to do that on multiple columns.  Is pandas the wrong choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are 2 issues here.

This is an artifice that makes the syntax a little nicer

```
In [111]: idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

1) Your `.query` does not have the correct precedence. The `&` operator has a higher precedence than comparison operators like `<=` and needs parentheses around its left and right operands.

```
In [102]: result3 = mdt.query("(@test_A-@eps_A <= A <= @test_A+@eps_A) & (@test_B-@eps_B <= B <= @test_B+@eps_B) & (@test_C-@eps_C <= C <= @test_C+@eps_C) & (@test_D-@eps_D <= D <= @test_D+@eps_D)").set_index(['A','B','C','D']).sortlevel()
```

This is your original query using MultiIndex slicers

```
In [103]: result1 = mdt2.loc[idx[test_A-eps_A:test_A+eps_A,test_B-eps_B:test_B+eps_B,test_C-eps_C:test_C+eps_C,test_D-eps_D:test_D+eps_D],:]
```

Here is a chained version of this query. IOW its a repeated selection on the result set.

```
In [104]: result2 = mdt2.loc[idx[test_A-eps_A:test_A+eps_A],:].loc[idx[:,test_B-eps_B:test_B+eps_B],:].loc[idx[:,:,test_C-eps_C:test_C+eps_C],:].loc[idx[:,:,:,test_D-eps_D:test_D+eps_D],:]
```

Always confirm correctness before working on performance

```
In [109]: (result1==result2).all().all()
Out[109]: True

In [110]: (result1==result3).all().all()
Out[110]: True
```

Performance

The `.query` IMHO will actually scale very well and uses multi-cores. For a large selection set this will be the way to go

```
In [107]: %timeit mdt.query("(@test_A-@eps_A <= A <= @test_A+@eps_A) & (@test_B-@eps_B <= B <= @test_B+@eps_B) & (@test_C-@eps_C <= C <= @test_C+@eps_C) & (@test_D-@eps_D <= D <= @test_D+@eps_D)").set_index(['A','B','C','D']).sortlevel()
10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop
```

2) The original multi-index slicing. There is an issues here, see below. I am not sure exactly why this is non-performant, and will investigate this [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10287)

```
In [106]: %timeit  mdt2.loc[idx[test_A-eps_A:test_A+eps_A,test_B-eps_B:test_B+eps_B,test_C-eps_C:test_C+eps_C,test_D-eps_D:test_D+eps_D],:]
1 loops, best of 3: 4.34 s per loop
```

Repeated selections make this quite performant. Note that I won't normally recommend one do this as you cannot assign to it, but for this purpose it is ok.

```
In [105]: %timeit mdt2.loc[idx[test_A-eps_A:test_A+eps_A],:].loc[idx[:,test_B-eps_B:test_B+eps_B],:].loc[idx[:,:,test_C-eps_C:test_C+eps_C],:].loc[idx[:,:,:,test_D-eps_D:test_D+eps_D],:]
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop
```

Comment: `DataFrame.query` FTW!

Comment: Thanks, Jeff!  This was helpful, although it seems like the basic answer is "you can't do better than query".  It does seem strange that there isn't a way to take advantage of sorted data.

Also, this seems to indicate that the parens aren't needed (although of course they never hurt):
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-python-versus-pandas-syntax-comparison

Comment: The docs don't cover the case of a chained comparison ``a <= val <= b`` AND multiple expressions, where they are necessary. Further, the indexer DO take advantage of sortedness. In general unless you are looking for individual values this doesn't make much difference though, as you are looking for arbitrary ranges / list-likes here. Depending on what you are actually selecting, you might be better off using a disk-based row store (e.g. ``HDFStore``), but YMMV.

Comment: Yeah, maybe something like pytables would work better for this particular application.. Thanks again!